# Selected option not showing at top of dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dropdown that is populated from all the titles in the database table seminars. I want the first option to be the option that is selected in the featured table using the seminarsID. The "Top Feature" shows the first option properly. The "2nd Feature" is blank when you see the drop down box, but when you click to see all the options the first option is the correct one from the featured table.

Here's the code:

```
<div class='formInput'>Top Feature: <select name='seminarID1' id='seminarID1'>
<?php
    $myquery = mysql_query("
        SELECT id, title
        FROM seminars
        WHERE id in 
        (SELECT seminarsID from featured WHERE ID = 1)
    ");

    while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myquery)){?>
        <option value='<?php echo $get_row['id']?>'><?php echo $get_row['title'];
    ?></option><?php }

    $rs = mysql_query("
        SELECT id, title 
        FROM seminars
        WHERE Active = 'Active'
        order by title
    ");

    while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
        echo "<option value='{$get_row['id']}'>{$get_row['title']}</option>";
?>
</select></div>

<div class='formInput'>2nd Feature: <select name='seminarID2' id='seminarID2'>
<?php
    $myquery = mysql_query("
        SELECT id, title
        FROM seminars
        WHERE id in
        (SELECT seminarsID from featured WHERE ID = 2)
    ");

    while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myquery)){?>
        <option value='<?php echo $get_row['id']?>'><?php echo $get_row['title'];
    ?></option><?php }

    $rs = mysql_query("
        SELECT id, title
        FROM seminars
        WHERE Active = 'Active'
        order by title
    ");

    while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
        echo "<option value='{$get_row['id']}'>{$get_row['title']}</option>";

?>
 </select></div>
```

Comment: @user1810546 Not even close

Comment: Unless I mangled your code during reformatting, it looks like you are failing to close the `<option>` tags inside the third `while` loop.

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: Line 36 in the code above (the third `while()` loop). The `</option>` is after the loop closes.

Comment: I fixed that but it didn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Will you update your post with the corrected code?

Comment: In the same line, there is a missing single quote: `?></option><?php `. The quote should be just after the `>` and before `</option>`. You may wish to convert the encapsulation to double-quotes on both ends for best results.

Comment: I believe that's incorrect as there's already a single quote at the end of the value: <option value='<?php echo $get_row['id']?>'>

Comment: Yes, you are right. Have you confirmed that the query that generates options for the non-working select is returning the expected results?

Comment: Yes, it is. I would like to upload an image of what's happening but I don't have a high enough reputation.

Comment: This is interesting. I just checked it in a different browser and it's working FINE. It looks like it's only an issue in Chrome.

Comment: It's working fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE. Does anyone have an idea of what is going wrong?